# NSOperation Subclass performance or leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Following is the subclass implementation of NSOperation Subclass
The operation will be use to asynchronously download Image from server.

```
-(void) main{

    @autoreleasepool {
      //NSURLConnection
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"A URl"]];
        _downloadConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
}

-(BOOL)isConcurrent{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)isExecuting{
    return _isExecuting;
}

-(BOOL)isFinished{
    return _isFinished;
}

-(void)finish{

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished  =YES;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

-(void)cancel{

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished  =YES;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [connection cancel];
    connection=nil;
    [self finish];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    //Other Code
    [connection cancel];
    connection=nil;
    [self finish];
}
```

Please let me know if there might be anything that I might have missed out within the code, so as to avoid leaks and check all KVO are handled properly.

Comment: It's curious to ask about leaking. Is there some reason you suspect a leak?

Comment: Yes Rob, this operation's will be added to the operation queue and will be download images. So, wanted to avoid leaks.

Comment: I know you want to avoid leaks. It's just strange to post a question "does this leak". Usually one would have identified a leak and ask "why does this leak". Not a big deal, but just weird. As it turns out, since you never terminate the operations, there probably would be some modest leaks (fixed by remedying `finished` method, as discussed below). But you don't seem to be doing anything with any images here, so it's hard to identify whether images, themselves, might leak.

Comment: Unrelated, but have you considered using something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which already wraps requests in operation subclass quite elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

1. Your `finish` and `cancel` routines are calling `willChangeValueForKey` twice for each key. Obviously that second call should be `didChangeValueForKey`.
2. I would advise against implementing `cancel` method. The default implementation does some other stuff. Do not implement that method. If you really want to, there are changes I'd advise here (at very least, cancel connection, too; call `super`; some other things, too), but I'd simply advise against implementing it at all and detect cancellation in `didReceiveData` (see point #5).
3. This code does not appear to be setting `_isExecuting` (nor do appropriate KVO) when the operation starts. Maybe that's in a `start` method you neglected to share with us?
4. Likewise, that `start` method should check to see if the operation has been canceled already and if so, stop the operation immediately.
5. In `didReceiveData`, are you checking `isCancelled`, as well? Making operations cancelable is one of the main reasons you use operation queues.
6. You're starting a `NSURLConnection` within an operation (presumably with the intent to add this operation to some random queue). But `NSURLConnection` will not work correctly unless you either schedule it on the main run loop (the easy solution) or you create your own run loop alive (there are a variety of techniques of that).

   For example, to tell the operation to schedule the connection in the main run loop, you could do something like:

   ```
   _downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:FALSE];
   [_downloadConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runLoopModes:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
   [_downloadConnection start];
   ```

   I'm typing that without benefit of Xcode, so if I mistyped a method forgive me, but it illustrates the idea: Create connection with `startImmediately` of `FALSE`, schedule it on the main run loop, and only then should you `start` it.
7. If `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called, it is entirely unnecessary to call `[connection cancel]`.
8. As of iOS 7, `isConcurrent` has been deprecated in favor of `isAsynchronous`. If you need to support earlier iOS versions, though, keep `isConcurrent`.
9. By the way, while I think it might work the way you've laid it out, it is generally advised to implement properties called `executing` and `finished`:

   ```
    @property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter=isExecuting) BOOL executing;
    @property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter=isFinished)  BOOL finished;
   ```

   I then manually synthesize:

   ```
    @synthesize finished  = _finished;
    @synthesize executing = _executing;
   ```

   And then I implement manual setters (but rely upon the synthesized getters and ivars):

   ```
   - (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
   {
       if (_executing != executing) {
           [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
           _executing = executing;
           [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
       }
   }

   - (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
   {
       if (_finished != finished) {
           [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
           _finished = finished;
           [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
       }
   }
   ```

   But if you do that, you can now just set `self.executing = FALSE` (or whatever) and it (a) does appropriate KVO, saving you from littering your code with all sorts of KVO calls; and (b) but saves you from having to implement properties and getters manually.

Comment: Good points. I would add that calls to `-didChangeValueForKey:` should be done in reverse order from the corresponding calls to `-willChangeValueForKey:`. That is, they should be treated as nested. For concurrent (asynchronous) operations, one must override `-start` and the override must *not* call through to super. One may or may not override `-main`, but it won't be called automatically. If you want it to be called, you must call it yourself.

Comment: I didn't suggest he has to call `-start`. I said he has to call `-main` if he wants it to be called.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment about "calling it yourself". I thought you were talking about `start`, but you were talking about `main`. Quite right on all counts.

Comment: The suggestion about using declared properties may not work. I haven't checked if they compensated for it, but as originally designed `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` have a problem: they use KVO on keys "isExecuting", "isReady", "isFinished", etc. But a property "executing" doesn't emit change notifications for "isExecuting" (even if that is the name of its getter), it emits change notifications for "executing". Furthermore, if something observes "isExecuting", KVO won't hook into `-setExecuting:`, it will hook into `-setIsExecuting:`.

Comment: That's why I said that you have to implement custom setters which post the non-standard KVO. I'll make that more clear. But if you look at the new `NSOperation` headers, they define properties much like the above.

Comment: The clarification helps. Thanks. I realize that the headers have changed to using declared properties but a) they're read-only so whether there are (private) setters and what they might do is not affected by that change, and b) the implementers (Apple) know about the KVO key mismatch while newbies would not.

Comment: Agreed, there's more than one way to skin the cat. The public `readonly` properties with and private `readwrite` properties is a very common pattern, and all we have to do it implement the custom setters, which isolates the infuriatingly non-standard KVO code in one place, rather than littering it about the `NSOperation` subclass. I use the above pattern frequently and it works perfectly fine and, IMHO, is more consistent with the properties that Apple has now exposed.

Comment: @Rob You explained very well all the points. Few queries Why would NSURLConnection won't start from a NSOperationQueue. Why mainRunloop, its not a UI update?

Comment: `NSURLConnection` needs a run loop. If you start the connection in a background queue, there is no run loop on that thread (unless you manually add one) and as a result your delegate methods won't get called. This is just a `NSURLConnection` idiosyncrasy. Some solutions (like AFNetworking) implement a dedicated thread. But network connections require so little CPU that doing it on the main thread is perfectly fine (and it's the easiest way to implement this).